# How to sort products in ascending order price

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

How to sort products in ascending order of price.
The price is created as follows: Price from models Products are multiplied by Volume from models Pack.
This is how the price is displayed for all products on Laravel

```
ceil(
    (
        $product->packs->count() > 0 
            ? $product->packs->sortBy('pivot.add_time')->first()->volume 
            : 1
    ) * $product->price
)
```

I tried to use this code, but the error

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::$pack

```php
if ($request->get('sort') == 'sort-price_desc') {
    $products = Product::orderBy(
        function ($product) {
            return ceil(
                ($product->packs->count() > 0 
                     ? $product->packs->sortBy('pivot.add_time')->first()->volume 
                     : 1) * $product->price
            );
         }
    )->get();
}
```

Comment: That's quite a lot of code that could potentially emit this warning. What is your understanding of the diagnostic message? Which simple expression in the code you posted emits this warning? For your general question, why doesn't the official documentation suffice? What is your concrete issue?