# How to sort products by price ascending for price filter

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a filter that sorts products by a given price range written in Laravel.
But I don't know how to sort items in ascending order of price. Here is the code itself.

```
if ($request->get('min_price') > 0 || $request->get('max_price') > 0) {

            $minPrice = $request->get('min_price');
            $maxPrice = $request->get('max_price');
            $products = Product::whereIn('id', $product_ids)->published();
            $products = Product::whereHas('packs', function ($query) use ($minPrice, $maxPrice) {
                 $query->where('volume', '>', 0) // Check if the volume is greater than 0
                       ->whereRaw('price * volume >= ? AND price * volume <= ?', [$minPrice, $maxPrice])
             })->paginate(22);
           

         }
```

Comment: also potentially your own duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76793477/367456